# Visual Studio App Center - Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included when building Xamarin Forms app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

When building a Xamarin Forms app in Visual Studio App Center it complains about the embedded xaml-files when using `netstandard2.0`.

Locally with updated Visual Studio and Xamarin Forms it works perfect to build and run.

> (CheckForDuplicateItems target) ->
>   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(276,5):
>   error : Duplicate 'EmbeddedResource' items were included. The .NET SDK
>   includes 'EmbeddedResource' items from your project directory by
>   default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or
>   set the 'EnableDefaultEmbeddedResourceItems' property to 'false' if
>   you want to explicitly include them in your project file. For more
>   information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems.

How should xaml-files be added to the project if not as embedded?

UPDATE:

The same error is present using VSTS and Hosted Mac Agent

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `.csproj` file and remove the `ItemGroup` that contains the `EmbeddedResource`.

This resolved the issue from me but the original answer came from [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104952/duplicate-embeddedresource-items-were-included-after-migrate-to-net-standard)